# Designing a stats experiment on Life Time Value (LTV) of the customers of a subscription product

Tags: t-test, experiment-design

I work for a subscription product that has two different channels in which customers can subscribe. Let's call them channel A (website) and channel B (mobile application). I have a hypothesis that customer's that subscribe via channel B don't retain as long as those that subscribe using channel A. One way I thought I could test my hypothesis is by comparing the value of the customers in terms of how much they have paid us (let's call this Life Time Value (LTV)). See sample data below:

```
Channel A subscriber LTV | Channel B subscriber LTV
$10                      | $5
$20                      | $10 
$0                       | $2
$5                       | $15
...                      | ...
```

Channel B receives more traffic, which means the ratio of my samples is almost 3:1 (I have 3000 data points for channel B and 1000 data points for channel A).

To test my hypothesis I considered using a t-test, but I really don't know if this is the right approach for this problem. I read that a t-test shouldn't be used for very large sample sizes, and I also realize that my data doesn't follow a Gaussian distribution. Below is a histogram for channel B (y axis is subscribers, x axis is LTV in $):

[image]

Below is the histogram for channel A:

[image]

How would you approach testing my hypothesis? I really wish I'd taken more stats in university.

Comment: I would analyze more metrics such as: time how long customer retains, frequency and regularity of purchases, monetary value per groups - for example: demographic characteristics if available. Maybe experiment should answer question and explore what channel use to reach groups?

Comment: t test is OK regardless of sample size. (You might have read something about using z test if $n > 30,$ but disregard that here.) // For a 2-sample t test, you check normality _separately_ for each of the two variables. Your histogram seems to be for all 2000_1000 = 3000 taken together. Still I wonder if each sample separately is normal. Can you show 2 separate histograms? // Is the question whether individual subscribers in A have larger LTV than those in B? Or whether A? Or whether channel A or B provides more overall profit?

Comment: Hi BruceET. I should have clarified further. That's the histogram for channel B. I edited my question to explain this better, and I also added a histogram for channel A. Thanks for the clarification regarding the t-test. My hypothesis is in fact that subscribers from channel A have a larger LTV than those of channel B. If I'm not wrong the t-test could demonstrate with statistical significance that the average LTV of one channel is greater than the other. I ran the t-test using excel and calculated a very small P values: 3.09749E-16

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this very small P value demonstrates that there is in fact a statistical difference between the means of channel A and channel B. Given that B has a larger mean, my hypothesis is incorrect. It looks like subscribers from channel B have a greater mean LTV. 

Does using a t-test make sense for the distributions you see in the histograms?